# API for approval app in teams -is there is any rest api is available for new approval app in teams?

Tags: rest, graph, microsoft-teams

is there is any rest api is available for new approval app in teams

Send, receive, manage, and share approvals in Microsoft Teams
The hub for your approvals across all systems that you create, manage, and share. Get things done quickly with the ability to review and take action right in Microsoft Teams. To use this app, you need to have an F3 license or above. Contact your admin if you're unable to use the app.

or any graph api request for teams approval app , i am good with ui usage in teams

plan to integrated for conversation flow of my bot do to this integration need api to integrate with my bot , i am not at all got any things related to api of rest and graph

thanks
rajamanikkam.b

Comment: I don't think we have any API for approval app for teams. Let me take this for internal team discussion and update with resolution.

Answer (score 3):

As of 19/1/2021, We don't have Graph API's for teams approval app. If you need this feature to be released in future releases, Please raise a uservoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)

Comment: May we have updates for current status? Thank you.

Comment: We have a requirement to list all history approvals. We know Approval app has similiar function but it is cumbersome to find old records in thousands approvals.