# Is there an API for Teams Approval (Follow up)

Tags: .net, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

This is a follow question from the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770255/api-for-approval-app-in-teams-is-there-is-any-rest-api-is-available-for-new-app), is there is any rest api available for the approval app in teams?  If so, could someone share a reference?

Tried researching on google, youtube and code project to no avail.  Only can find references to GraphAPI and Power Automate and workflow.

Comment: Currently there is no API available for the above scenario. You can suggest this feature at [Microsft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).